# How do I write a default value to a Column where the default value is a value created from a function that uses another Column?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, docx, python-docx

Make flask-app, that is used .docx file (home/user/WebApp/app/docxfiles/*.docx) and display them using sqlalchemy. Using MySQL. Columns are written from flask-admin. Here's a piece of code that you can't do right. How do I write a default value to a Сolumn where the default value is a value created from a function that uses another Сolumn?

```
class Item(db.Model):
    def getinfo(namefile):
        path_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + "/docxfiles/" + namefile
        doc = docx.Document(path_file)
        fulltext = []
        for i in doc.paragraphs:
            fulltext.append(i.text)
        body = '\n\n'.join(fulltext)
        return re.sub('<(.|\n)*?>','',body)

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    namefile = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True)
    info = db.Column(db.String(16777216), server_default = getinfo(namefile))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column default values passed as `server_default` or `default` values are useful for setting fixed default values or date or timestamps but do not accept runtime arguments to allow more complex processing such as in your example. The correct place to put such code is in a constructor to your model class which will be called only on creation of a new object but not when an object is retrieved from the database. The only changes needed in your code to make this work is to turn the `getinfo` function into  an `__init__` method and to manually set the values of `namefile` and `info`.

```
class Item(db.Model):
    def __init__(self, namefile):
        path_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + "/docxfiles/" + namefile
        doc = docx.Document(path_file)
        fulltext = []
        for i in doc.paragraphs:
            fulltext.append(i.text)
        body = '\n\n'.join(fulltext)

        self.info = re.sub('<(.|\n)*?>','',body)
        self.namefile = namefile

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    namefile = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True)
    info = db.Column(db.String(16777216))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do it through the admin panel (flask-admin)?